# React router private routes / redirect not working with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to setup protected routes where the user is redirected to /login page if they arent logged in but it doesnt work when using redux.

This is my ProtectedRoute component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import { authenticate } from './actions';

const ProtectedRoute = ({
  component: Component, authenticate, isAuthenticated, ...rest
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    authenticate();
  });

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => (isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      ))
      }
    />
  );
};

ProtectedRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  authenticate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  authenticate,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProtectedRoute);
```

And here is the routes:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

Now before you mark this as a duplicate I have tried solutions in other threads.

Using `withRouter` doesnt work.

```
withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProtectedRoute))
```

Same thing with `{pure: false}`

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, {pure: false})(ProtectedRoute);
```

I also use `Switch`. I am not sure how to get this to work.

Comment: Please share your authenticate action and the reducer, it will help to see the flow of the action in your code.

Comment: @jank They work. It even shows in redux devtools. There is something wrong with react router.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use HOC component to check authentication?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default ChildComponent => {
  class ComposedComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      this.shouldNavigateAway();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.shouldNavigateAway();
    }
    shouldNavigateAway() {
      if (!this.props.auth) {
        this.props.history.push('/');
      }
    }
    render() {
      return <ChildComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { auth: state.auth.authenticated };
  }
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(ComposedComponent);
};
```

Now you only need to do is import this component to the protected component, and export the protected component like below,

```
import authCheck from 'blah/blah...'

export default authCheck(ProtectedComponent)
```

Comment: Hi. I could possibly solve this with a HOC but I am just curious as to why my code doesnt work.